# Hibernate Configuration Error - Fetching children failed with DocumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, hibernate-mapping

I am getting a following hibernate configuration problem -

[image]

Previously it was working fine and I was able to connect with postgres but now its not working.

hibernate.cfg.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/drc</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">drcschema</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping resource="UserProfile.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Full Stack Trace-

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.isValid(ConsoleConfigurationMainTab.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.refresh(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.updateButtons(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.updateLaunchConfigurationDialog(AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab$1.runInUIThread(AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException cannot be found by org.hibernate.eclipse.console_3.7.1.Final-v20131205-0918-B107
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the missing dependency to your maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download the jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1) and include in your classpath

Comment: I can see dom4j-1.6.1.jar in `Maven Dependencies` after adding this dependency but I am still getting the same error.